# When using a Primera-Line Wattage and Current Meter, is it showing AC or DC measurements?

Tags: amplifier, inverter, mains, watts, meter

I am new to the electrical engineering stuff and am looking for some guidance.

I'm going to be designing a off-grid power system for some devices. So I will need to get the power measurements from them. The devices are DC but come with invertors. I'm placing the Wattage meter between the UK mains outlet and the plug on the invertor, are these readings in AC or are these DC readings? The meter doesn't specify.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's inline with the mains supply then it can only measure that AC supply. Voltage and current readings will be AC.

If you have further specific questions then please link to the manual in your question.

Comment: Thank you, Transistor!